# Wierd asp.net session fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I recently encountered a weird issue with asp.net session which actually occurred in the sample code below.

Code that created a session (Login.aspx.cs)

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await request_login();
            if (canLogin == true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
            }
         }

   private async Task request_login()
        {
            // call web service with httpClient
               Session["key"] = "session object to be stored";
        }
}
```

Code that calls the session (Dashboard.aspx.cs)

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String sessionDetails = Session["key"] as String;
        }
     }
```

When I ran this piece of code, I got an empty string from the `Session["Key"]`. I managed to solve this issue with a weird fix by adding a dummy session in my home.aspx file (which is essentially the default page of the website).

Home.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //wierd fix that allows session access
            Session["home"] = "fromHome";
        }
    }
```

After adding `Session["home"]`, my `Session["key"]` was able to work perfectly. Why did this occur? Shouldn't `Session["key"]` be able to work perfectly without needing to add `Session["home"]` in home.aspx.cs?

Comment: i think its because request_login is not getting executed. since you have made it an async task. as soon as it hits response.redirect the execution of request_login stops and control is given to dashboard,aspx

Comment: Async void makes no sense during request processing... No idea what behavior you expect from that code - especially when it runs after request is ended...

Comment: @Mysterio11, hmmm but btn_login() does an await against request_login so it the async task should still finish its implementation before the response.redirect has taken place

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, ya but if i do not make btn_login() an async void method, i would not be able to do an await request_login()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await request_login();
            if (canLogin == true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx",false);
            }
         }

   private async Task request_login()
        {
            // call web service with httpClient
               Session["key"] = "session object to be stored";
        }
}
```

So this will not abort the thread.

If you want to know the exact reason of why this happen visit this : 
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_

Comment: Thanks, that really solved the problem. I have a question though, why would the thread being aborted affect the storing of the session? isn't the session in a sense already stored?